# PHP - $_SESSION doesn't set

Tags: php, session

I have a register form for users. When they click in create account it goes to  the insertUser.php page that will insert the user in the database and will create a $_SESSION["message"]="Registration Complete. Proceed to login" in case the insert is done successfully. the inserUser.php page then redirects to the index.php page with the register form open so the user can see the message. But it shows an error of `Undefined Index: message`. I am doing the same thing in the login form to show errors and everything works fine so I don't know what is the problem.

here is my code, index.php:

```
<div class="register-form">
    <form action="insertUsers.php"  method="POST" id="formregisto" name="formregisto">
            <div>
            <input type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Nome de Utilizador" required/>
            </div>

            <div>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            </div>
            <div id="message"><?php if (!isset($_SESSION["message"])) print $_SESSION["message"]?> </div>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" name="criar" value="Create Account"/>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

insertUsers.php:

```
<?php
    include "include/config.php"; 

 $username= $_REQUEST['username'];
 $email= $_REQUEST['email'];
 $password= md5($_REQUEST['password']);

 if( !empty ($username) AND !empty ($email) AND !empty ($password)){
    $sql="insert into users(email, username, password) values ('$email', '$username','$password')"; 


    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);


if ($result)
    $_SESSION["message"]= "Registration Complete. Proceed to login";
     header('Location: index.php?openr=1');

 } else {
     $_SESSION["message"]= "Something went wrong, try again";
     header('Location: index.php?openr=1');
 }

?>
```

Comment: `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION["message"])) print $_SESSION["message"]?>` Don't you see what's wrong here? :)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @Dharman To be fair, he's using `md5`, which is still fine (though not as good as `password_hash`).

Comment: How is it still fine?

Comment: @Dharman `md5` is a hash function?

Comment: @Jeto It is equivalent to plain text in terms of security. There is barely any difference.

Comment: @Dharman ??? It may not be as secure as other hashing methods, but it's still ten thousand times better than storing in plain text.

Comment: @Jeto No! It is not. MD5 without any unique salt is basically obfuscated plain text. There is no security there. Search for MD5 rainbow tables.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: @Dharman I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying this is not plain text, and still much better. Rainbow tables exist for any unsalted hashing method anyway, not just md5. Basically, password_hash is much better than manually salted md5 which is much better than unsalted md5 which is *still* definitely better than plain text, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Jeto Please read more about secure password storage. You should not defend MD5 for password hashing under any circumstances. This is not a place to continue such discussion.

Comment: @Dharman Your first comment is wrong and misleading is all I'm saying (this is not plain text). "Use a better hashing method" would have been correct.

Comment: @user1264 in addition to the logical bug, you should also include session_start() statement at the beginning of the script so as to read the values stored in $_SESSION. Please refer this link: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

`<?php if (!isset($_SESSION["message"])) print $_SESSION["message"]?>`

That's what you wrote, it's not gonna display because of the `!` you added.  Kindly remove it and your code should work fine but you might still have a warning saying that message is undefined.

But your SQL syntax is really bad, you didn't escape user inputs.
Don't trust your visitors!

Comment: Do not recommend suppressing warnings.